# Azure Media Services - Stream resuming?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, mpeg-dash

I have a problem with Azure Media Services. It's configured to get stream from RTMP source, then encode it to multiple resolutions (pretty standard i think). But the problem is, that when the source stream ends (for example, powers goes down or internet disconnects) and I resume streaming it doesn't come back, so to speak.
The only thing that anyone using the player can see is the slate, that I've set up.
It happens with every piece of software that I could use, that is OBS, FLE, vMix.
Stream is published all the time, and I'm using DefaultProgram, but this happens anyway, doesn't matter if on Default or created manually.

If anyone has an idea what's going on, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you tried to reset the channel?

Comment: @rnrneverdies Yeah resetting works, but that's not an option in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you disconnect the streaming ingesting, the current solution is to restart the channel.